# How to move a navbar item to the first place when the hamburger menu is visible?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm building a new website with Bootstrap and I have a NavBar, it looks fine in any desktop or tablet since it has its links and the Search Box at the right corner:

[image: preview 1]

However, I feel somehow inconvenient in the mobile devices to have the search at the bottom of the menu:

[image: preview 2]

This is a Fiddle of my example code:

https://jsfiddle.net/hpxgowa8/

This is the general code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Gravity Now!</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Calculator</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Comparison</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'd like to know if anyone knows what could I change to move the Search Box as the first element when the hamburger menu is visible?

Comment: Use a [css grid solution](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) here when displaying a mobile resolution. This gives you the power to place the items in any order you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty easy to achieve with flexbox too, if you set navbar-collapse wrapper as a flex item, you can change the `order`of its contents:

```
 .navbar-collapse {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 }

 .form-inline {
    order: -1;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dgz7h01w/

Answer (score 0):

The following grid solution will work:

By using a grid `display: grid` on the `div`. The `div` get divided into two parts. The first `row` is defined in `grid-template-rows` to be set at 25% and the rest to 75% since the menu is divided into a list and form.

Then use `grid-row` to set the search bar to row 1 and the list to row 2 and presto.

```css
#navb  {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 75%;
}

#navb > ul.navbar-nav {
  grid-row: 2;
}

#navb > form.form-inline.my-2.my-lg-0 {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Gravity Now!</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Calculator</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Comparison</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Mastering css-grids (combined with flex boxes) is powerful addition to your css-skills. Check this [link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) to see if it meets the compatibility for your project and learn more about grids [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Awesome! I'm going to study them in detail during the week! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is pretty bad coding architecture. You propose a solution which requires knowing (and hard-coding) the height ratio between child and parent when all that was required was a change in order (height agnostic). Imagine you have a dynamic menu item (only appears on some pages or in a particular state). Or that one of the menu items is an accordion. You now need JS to update the ratio of the grid, cross-browser. A lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu grid and flex box solutions are flexible and the provided sample is just a proof of concept. Of course you can also change the position of an element dynamically, use floats or something else. The above sample - based on the provided sample - works; again as a proof of concept with me advising to further expand on grids and flex boxes.